# Possible reasons for column not converting from factor to numeric

Tags: r, class, dataframe

I looked up the answer on these threads but none are working in my case:

[R change all columns of type factor to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596466/r-change-all-columns-of-type-factor-to-numeric),

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f,

[How to convert a data frame column to numeric type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)

I am working with a data frame (8600 x 168) which I imported:

`originaldf2<-read.csv("Occupanyrate_Train")`. Apart from the first three columns, all are numeric values. Many of the columns are of class `factor` after importing. I need all columns from 3 to 168 in the numeric class for analysis. There were a number of empty values and "-" in these columns which I converted to NAs by doing this:

`originaldf2[originaldf2=="-"]=NA` `originaldf2[originaldf2==""]=NA`. The columns contain nothing but decimal numbers, Integers and NAs. I tried using the following command to convert all variables to numeric class:

`originaldf2<-as.numeric(as.character(originaldf2[ , 4:168]))` and I get the error: `Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion` and my dataframe itself becomes strange:

`str(originaldf2)
 num [1:165] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`

I also tried: `as.numeric(levels(originaldf2))[as.integer(originaldf2)]`

to try and coerce the whole dataframe but I got the error `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'`

Then I noticed that there are unused levels which might be the reason, so I dropped the unused levels: `originaldf2<-str(drop.levels(originaldf2))` and tried to again coerce but still not happening! Here's a subset of the df (10 x 12):

`Property_ID  Month Zipcode Occupancy_Rate.Response.Variable. VAR_1 VAR_2     VAR_3
1     A3FF8CD6 13-Jan   30064                              0.93   468    10 0.7142857
2     A3FF8CD6 13-Feb   30064                              0.93   468    10 0.7142857
3     A3FF8CD6 13-Mar   30064                              0.94   468    10 0.7142857
4     A3FF8CD6 13-Apr   30064                              0.96   468    10 0.7142857
5     A3FF8CD6 13-May   30064                             0.953   468    10 0.7142857
6     A3FF8CD6 13-Jun   30064                              0.93   468    10 0.7142857
7     A3FF8CD6 13-Jul   30064                             0.925   468    10 0.7142857
8     A3FF8CD6 13-Aug   30064                             0.925   468    10 0.7142857
9     A3FF8CD6 13-Sep   30064                              0.95   468    10 0.7142857
10    A3FF8CD6 13-Oct   30064                             0.945   468    10 0.7142857
11    A3FF8CD6 13-Nov   30064                               0.9    NA  <NA>        NA
12    A3FF8CD6 13-Dec   30064                             0.945    NA  <NA>        NA
       VAR_4 VAR_5 VAR_6
1  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
2  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
3  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
4  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
5  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
6  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
7  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
8  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
9  0.5714286   0.8  0.75
10 0.5714286   0.8  0.75
11        NA    NA    NA
12        NA    NA    NA`

Comment: use `originaldf2 <- read.csv("Occupanyrate_Train.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and try again

Comment: `stringAsFactors` is not as argument in `read.csv` i think . . . i'm getting the error: `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (stringAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: `stringsAsFactors` is not an argument to `read.csv` directly, but it is to `read.table`, which is subsequently called.

Comment: I didn't know read.csv would work without a .csv extension

Comment: so I added the `stringsAsFactors` argument and tried: `originaldf<-as.numeric(as.character(originaldf[ ,c(sprintf("VAR_%.i", 1:164))]))` since I want all variables columns from 1 to 164 changed to numeric but its not working ! same error - `Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `na.strings` argument to convert `-` to `NA` while reading:

```
x <- read.csv(na.strings=c('-'),
text="a,b,c
0,,
-,1,2")

 x
   a  b  c
1  0 NA NA
2 NA  1  2
```

Blank values are converted to `NA` automatically in numeric columns.  It is the `-` values that are forcing the column to be interpreted as `factor`.

Comment: oh man! what a mountain molehill story. thanks. Out of interest, if I don't use the `na.strings` to change "-" to NA while reading the file, but replace the "-" after importing with `NA` and then drop unused levels, is there no way of changing class from factor to numeric?

Comment: @vagabond As far as I'm aware (and I'm sure that someone will correct me if I'm wrong), you would have to do it column-by-column, for example with `lapply`.

Answer (score 4):

The advice to use `stringsAsFactors` will only get you so far. It appears that you probably want to use colClasses as well. It will both coerce the desired columns to numeric and create NA's that are appropriate.

```
originaldf <- read.csv( file_name, 
                        colClasses=c(rep( "character",3), rep("numeric", 6) ) )
```

This also makes input  happen (much, much) faster for large dataframes since the logic that is used to guess at the classes is bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `read.csv` statement. It'll work.

Comment: Nope. It's definitely not working this way ! With `stringAsFactors=FALSE`, my columns are read as class: character which is a step closer I am sure. if I state that as TRUE, they stay as class factor.